# find location of point from texture in final rendering

Tags: python, mesh, texturing, uv

I am creating synthetic documents using the following method:

I take a mesh of a page,
[image: mesh]

add to it the texture from a pdf file
[image: texture]

add a bit of random rotation, and render.
[image: final rendered image]

All of this is done via the bpy python interface. I would need to find out the location of a point from the texture in the world of the final rendered image. Specifically, I would like to feed the rendering script a list of coordinates from the original texture and output the corresponding list of coordinates from the rendered image.

In short:
[image: what I want]

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand that you want to do. It seems you can use UV pass somehow

Comment: I added an image at the end to make clear what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In cycles you can enable UV pass in view layer settings:

[image]

Using this layer, you can get a UV coords position of each point on render. Red color corresponds to U and Green - to V.

[image]

So if you want to find a specific point on source image, get X and Y coordinates and get the color from formula: RGB(X\width, Y\height, 100%), then find the closest color in UV layer.  Color information should be saved in EXR to avoid Rec709 <-> sRGB color transformations.

Comment: This works great! Thanks! However, searching for each point of interest in such a large grid is quite time consuming. Does perhaps the bpy interface have a command which can do this quickly? Otherwise, I will try to build an optimized search in the area which I think the next point should be.

Comment: I managed to achieve a much faster search using gradient descent. Thanks!